# Need help reasoning through a simple proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm reading Solow's book on proofs and simultaneously going through a college algebra book which has some proofs in it so I want to see if my reasoning is correct.  When proving something we assume that the hypothesis is true and we try to prove the conclusion.

The problem "Show that $(a+b)=a^2+b^2$ $\iff$ $a=0$ or $b=0$" is an iff statement so I need to prove that $A\implies B$ and $B\implies A$.  I can set up the two statements as the following :

Statement 1. If $a=0$ or $b=0$ then $(a+b)=a^2+b^2$

Statement 2. If $(a+b)=a^2+b^2$ then $a=0$ or $b=0$

For statement 1 in order to assume that the hypothesis is true I need to just assume that either $a$ is $0$ or $b$ is $0$.  But would I also have to prove that if BOTH $a=0$ and $b=0$ are FALSE then that leads to the conclusion being false?

Also for statement 2 I assume that $(a+b)=a^2+b^2$ is true and have to show that either $a=0$ or $b=0$ is true and then do I have to show that if BOTH $a=0$ or $b=0$ are FALSE then the statement is false?

Comment: Do you mean $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2\iff a=0$ or $b=0$

Comment: Yes just fixed it

Comment: "But would I also have to prove that if BOTH a=0 and b=0 are FALSE"  Absolutely not.  N or M means either i) N but not M, ii) M but not N or iii) both M and N.  Basically, one or the other is true.  And possibly both are.

Comment: I'm sure you have a typo.  $a = 1$ and $b=1$ will yield $a+b = a^2 + b^2 = 2$ with neither $a=0$ or $b=0$.  I'm nearly certain you meant $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ which should be intuitively obvious as $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ and that can only equal $a^2 + b^2$ if (and only if) $2ab = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $a=0$, then $(a+b)^2=b^2=0^2+b^2$ is good so statement 1 is proved (because the equation is symmetrical in $a,b$, an analogous result holds for b).

If $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ then $2ab=0$ so that means, by null factor law, either $a=0$ or $b=0$ so that proves statement 2.

Comment: I dont think statement 1 is proved with just a=0.  I think you must also prove it with b=0.  It's possible for [$a = 0$ or $b0$] without $a = 0$.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks; I remember thinking it was so obvious that it didn't need an explanation. An explanation has been added

Comment: 95 % of the time I would agree with you.  But as this OP is very concerned about absolute and complete logic as to what "OR" means and *precisely* how we prove it, I think we do have to be very thourough.  I am the prove is simply $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2 = a^2 + b^2 \iff 2ab = 0 \iff a = 0$ or $b=0$.  But clearly the OP wants to know the *exact* logic and what *rules* are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you mean $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$?

If so it's $ab=0$, which gives which you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prove it is false if $a=0$ AND $b=0$.  $N$ or $M$ means ... $N$ or $M$.  It does NOT mean "not both".  If $a=0$ AND $b=0$ then it is true that $a=0$ so it is true that $a=0$ or $b=0$.

So so if

$A$ is $a=0$ or $b=0$ and $B$ is $ (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$ (I'm assuming that is the correct statement.)

Then you need to prove

1) $A \implies B$.

2) $B \implies A$.

If $A_1$ is $a=0$ and $A_2$ is $b=0$ to prove a $(A_1 $ or $A_2) \implies B$ question you must prove that

1a) $A_1 \implies B$

2a) $A_2 \implies B$.

Thus "one or the other imply $b$.

These are *TRIVIALLY* easy:

1a)  $a=0 \implies (a + b)^2 = (b)^2 = 0^2 + b^2 = a^2 + b^2$

To prove $B \implies (A_1$ or $ A_2)$ is a little subtler.

You can arbitrarily choice one of $A_1$ or $A_2$, say $A_1$.  Then either $A_1$ is true or it is not.  If it is true then ... well $A_1$ is true.  If it is not true then you must prove $B$ and NOT $A_1 \implies A_2$.  Then either $A_1$ is true (if $A_1$ is true) or $A_2$ is true (if $A_1$ is not true.)

So either way $(A_1 $ or $ A_2$) is true.

So to prove

2) $B \implies (A_1$ or $A_2$) is true$ you must prove both

Case 1: $A_1$

Then $B \implies A_1$.

There is nothing to prove.  If $A_1$ is true then ANYTHING $\implies A_1$ and we have nothing more to state.

and

Case 2: NOT $A_1$

Then $B \implies A_2$.

So prove $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 $ and $a\ne 0 \implies b= 0$.

Can you do that?

===

All things said though, I think you are being overly cautious and timid.

It should be a simple and acceptable to say.

1) If $a = 0$ or $b=0$ then EITHER $(a+b)^2 = b^2 = 0 + b^2 = a^2 + b^2$ OR $(a+b)^2 = a^2 =a^2 + 0 = a^2 + b^2$ so either way $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

2) If $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab +b^2 = a^2 + b^2$ then $2ab = 0$ and $ab=0$.

$ab = 0$ only if either $a =0$ or $b=$.

....

Was that too quick or uncertain  for you?

Another even more efficient proof is

$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + a^2$ and $a^2 + ab + a^2 = a^2 + b^2 \iff 2ab =0$.

And $2ab = 0 \iff a = 0$ or $ b=0$.

....

Is this a class on formalizing proofs or on learning the math.